# При запуске dconf-editor вылетает сессия Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux, сессия, linux-mint, gnome

```
# uname -a
Linux dexp 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Release:    17.3
Codename:   rosa
```

По-умолчанию стояла среда XFCE, я поставил Gnome3. При попытке запустить dconf-editor вылетает сессия, происходит завершение сеанса, появляется окно GDM.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего удивительного. Дистрибутивы, заточенные на широкий круг пользователей (наподобие ubuntu) изначально собирают под то окружение, в котором они поставляются. Весь софт и все конфиги в них ориентированы под изначальную среду. Если вам нужен стабильный гном - ставьте дистрибутив с гномом, если нужна гибкость - ставьте arch или собирайте свой.